# How to save excel file horizontally?

Tags: python, web-crawler

Hi I am a code newbie and I want to save data that I got through a website (editor.cnn.com) as an excel file but I don't get the result the way I want.

Because I want to save all the 'lines' or 'data' horizontally in an excel file.

So here is my code. Can you tell me what I have to change or add in my code?

Thank you in advance!

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jky9.png)

[after.. problem solved!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyQlr.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import NavigableString
import re

path = "/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)


nl = []

driver.get("https://edition.cnn.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
find_ingre = soup.select("div.cd__content")
for i in find_ingre:
    nl.append(i.get_text())

import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df_4 = pd.DataFrame(nl)
df_4
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'horizontally'? Please show expected sample.

Comment: Check the 'after' image on my post. 
Anyway problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pandas, you can use [openpxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create excel file:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Append all results as row
ws.append(nl)
wb.save("yourfile.xlsx")
```